# ¿Problema de arquitectura de carpetas?, una función que no funciona

Tags: javascript, php, html

Siempre intento reducir mis problemas a simples analogías, espero me entiendan.
estoy en un proyecto que tiene la siguiente arquitectura simple img:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que sucede es que, una función que está en el `archivo.js` cuyo resultado es --> `acción1`, solo se aplica en el `HTML1` y no en los demás HTML's, como muestro en la imagen. **¿Cómo hacer que la función(acción1) se aplique a todo los archivos html?**, **¿es un problema de arquitectura?** .

**Nota:** los archivos .js esta correctamente enlasado.

Comment: Te recomendamos leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Sin mirar el codigo es dificil saber en que parte es donde tienes la falla.

Comment: Sin código es imposible saber porque te ocurre, y podemos divagar durante horas distintas posibilidades hasta adivinar la correcta.  Así, de saque, diria que o bien los .js no estan correctamente enlazados tal como aseguras, o bien la función no está correctamente llamada, o bien no se aplica en los elementos que tu crees, o bien... (hay unos cuantos mas)

Comment: PERO LO UNICO QUE QUIERO SABER es, suponiendo que todo esta bien y correctamente enlazado. ¿Lo normal es que al hacer click en el "boton" realice la acción en los 3 archivos HTML o solo en el que contiene el boton?

Comment: @kraud, ¿revisaste la consola? Seguramente hay un error que no permite la ejecución del script.

Comment: Bueno ya lo resolví. Revise todo y todo esta correctamente enlazado; excepto por que estoy trabajando en un tema wordpress, y  la función wp_footer() que carga los script estaba al final de mi primer archivo( digamos html1) por lo tanto para los archivos que siguen html2,html3 no se le carga los script personalizados. La solución poner wp_footer() al final del ultimo archivo(html3).

Comment: para serrar la pregunta marcare la única respuesta que hay... Gracias!!! por comentar... me habéis guiado de alguna forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un archivo JS se ejecuta, o mejor dicho se evalua en cada página en la que se carga, lo que no quiere decir que tenga ningún efecto. Es independiente del número de páginas que tienes en el sitio / aplicación web, de como se enlazan o su arquitectura de carpetas, etc. El JS de una página HTML esta confinado a esa página, si bien puede cargarse y usarse en varias páginas, lo que hace o deja de hacer tiene efecto en cada una de esas páginas de forma independiente.

Te pondré un ejemplo.
Tenemos un fichero con este código:

```
console.log('Hola mundo');
```

Este código se evalua en cada documento *HTML* en el que lo cargues y escribe en la consola `Hola mundo`. Se ejecuta siempre porque no depende de ningún evento, condicional, etc.

Si el contenido del fichero JS fuera, por ejemplo:

```
if (document.querySelector('h3')) {
    console.log('Hola mundo');
}
```

El código se evalua, pero la línea que imprime en consola solo se ejecuta si la página tiene al memos un elemento `h3`.

Si la ejecución de esa línea dependiera de un evento, como pulsar un botón, se ejecutará en la página al pulsar ese botón, pero no se ejecuta en ninguna otra página que cargue ese mismo script, salvo que esa página tenga el mismo botón y se accione.

```
document.querySelector('button#boton_prueba').onclick = () => {
    console.log('Hola mundo');
}
```

Dicho esto hay formas de pasar un valor entre diferentes páginas HTML para ejecutar un mismo código JS. Lo más sencillo es guardar algo en *session* o *local storage* del navegador y ejecutar lo que se requiera en la página cuando se encuentra ese valor.

Comment: Gracias por responder, la solución a mi problema  como ya comente arriba era, poner la función wp_footer()(carga los scripts) al final de ultimo archivo ( en ejemplo de imagen seria en html3).  es como poner el script al final del html pero como wordpress seria "wp_footer".

Comment: @kraud si estas usando WP eso se avisa, que el código que hay dentro es un mundo misterioso.
Como esta hecho con PHP en realidad tus 3 HTML serán uno solo, el JS es el mismo para todos, ya si algo no funcione puede ser por el orden en que cargan los scripts, errores aparte, como que un botón intente ejecutar un script que aun no se ha cargado como parece tu caso. Si usas la consola del navegador salen esos errores.